# How to copy a YII project to another server?

Tags: yii

I have a Yii website and i want to copy it to another server on another machine, i place the file in my new web directory and try to access it and got error message "The 192.168.182.129 page isn’t working, 192.168.182.129 is currently unable to handle this request.HTTP ERROR 500" i created  a new project in my new web server and i and was able to access it, so i try to copy the backend folder in the old project to the new project i created but i got the same error, any help on how to copy it thanks

Comment: do you have any .htaccess file in your web directory? can you post your directory structure from web directory?

Comment: i try to search through my web directory for .htaccess file and in each of my project i found there are some .htaccess file. ./lesson/vendor/ezyang/htmlpurifier/benchmarks/.htaccess
./lesson/vendor/ezyang/htmlpurifier/maintenance/.htaccess
./lesson/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/.htaccess.....     ./trowbeal/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/.htaccess
where /lesson is my initial project and /trowbeal is my new project

Answer (score 0):

**BASIC APPLICATION**

1. **Renaming webroot**

Renaming webroot
Connect to your shared host using FTP or by other means. You will probably see something like the following:

```
config
logs
www
```

In the above, www is your webserver webroot directory. It could be named differently. Common names are: www, htdocs, and public_html.

The webroot in our basic project template is named web. Before uploading the application to your webserver rename your local webroot to match your server, i.e., from web to www, public_html or whatever the name of your hosting webroot.

2. **FTP root directory is writeable**

> If you can write to the root level directory i.e. where config, logs and www are, then upload assets, commands etc. as is to the root level directory.

3. **Add extras for webserver**

If your webserver is Apache you'll need to add an .htaccess file with the following content to web (or public_html or whatever) (where the index.php file is located):

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
IndexIgnore */*

RewriteEngine on

# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```

4. **Check requirements**

In order to run Yii, your webserver must meet its requirements. The very minimum requirement is PHP 5.4. In order to check the requirements copy requirements.php from your root directory into the webroot directory and run it via browser using http://example.com/requirements.php URL. Don't forget to delete the file afterwards.

**ADVANCE APPLICATION**

Deploying an advanced application to shared hosting is a bit trickier than a basic application because it has two webroots, which shared hosting webservers don't support. We will need to adjust the directory structure.

1. **Move entry scripts into single webroot**

First of all we need a webroot directory. Create a new directory and name it to match your hosting webroot name as described in Renaming webroot above, e.g., www or public_html or the like. Then create the following structure where www is the hosting webroot directory you just created:

```
www
    admin
backend
common
console
environments
frontend
...
```

**www** will be our frontend directory so move the contents of frontend/web into it. Move the contents of backend/web into www/admin. In each case you will need to adjust the paths in index.php and index-test.php.

2. **Separate sessions and cookies**

Originally the backend and frontend are intended to run at different domains. When we’re moving it all to the same domain the frontend and backend will be sharing the same cookies, creating a clash. It order to fix it, adjust backend application config backend/config/main.php as follows:

```
'components' => [
   'request' => [
    'csrfParam' => '_backendCSRF',
    'csrfCookie' => [
        'httpOnly' => true,
        'path' => '/admin',
    ],
   ],
  'user' => [
    'identityCookie' => [
        'name' => '_backendIdentity',
        'path' => '/admin',
        'httpOnly' => true,
    ],
   ],
  'session' => [
    'name' => 'BACKENDSESSID',
    'cookieParams' => [
        'path' => '/admin',
    ],
   ],
],
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me either, i'm using yii2 advance app, i try to copy all folders in my old project to the new project, and leave the index.php unchange but after copy everything the new project stop working, i don't really have idea what could be the problem i really need some help on this, thanks